# AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'centerx'

Tags: python, pygame

I am reading a book on Python, Python Crash Course and it used this code in a project.

```
import pygame

class Ship:
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen

        # load ship and get its rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        # start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen.bottom

    def blitme(self):
        # draw the ship at its current location
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

But it shows this error

```
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'centerx'
```

Comment: I don't think so. I think the book uses Python 3.5 and I have Python 3.8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.screen` is the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object which is associated to the screen. You have to get a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object with the size of the Surface by [`get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html):

```py
screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
self.rect.centerx = screen_rect.centerx
self.rect.bottom = screen_rect.bottom
```

Comment: Thanks... I had defined screen_rect but made the statement as screen.centerx. It worked perfectly after that.

Comment: Alright, I have done that. This was my first post so I did not know what to do after this. Thanks for the information.